# for loops in r are giving me a headache

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

```
a<-list(1:4)
for (i in a){
  print(i)
  print("should be between the numbers")
}
```

```
output:
[1] 1 2 3 4
[1] "should be between the numbers"
```

```
expected output:
[1] 1
[1] "should be between the numbers"
[2] 2
[2] "should be between the numbers"
[3] 3
[3] "should be between the numbers"
[4] 4
[4] "should be between the numbers"
```

Why does this happen and how can I get an output that looks closer to the expected output?

I want to be able to do something like:

```
list_of_data_frame_names<-list("bob","jill","jack")
list_of_data_frames<-list(bob,jill,jack)

a<-list(1:4)
for (i in a){
  q<-list_of_dataframes[[i]] %>% names() %>% length()
  b<-list(2:q)
  for (j in b){
    names(list_of_data[[i]])[j] <- paste(names(list_of_data[i]))[j], list_of_data_frame_names[i], sep="_")
}
```

I am working with several data sets that cover the same data but have different col names (expenses vs Expenses vs Total_Expenses for example), so I want to know which column came from which data set but don't want to do it all by hand. Note the inner loop works I have already tested it and I could just run it manually for each data set if I need to but that makes added data sets in the future harder and hard coding the same loop 8 times is hardly good coding practice.

Comment: The issue is the `list`. Use `a <- 1:4` instead of `a <- list(1:4)` and your code will work. Don't use lists when vectors will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store data in a list of length 4, right now you have data as list of length 1.

```
a <- as.list(1:4)
for (i in a) {
  print(i)
  print("should be between the numbers")
}

#[1] 1
#[1] "should be between the numbers"
#[1] 2
#[1] "should be between the numbers"
#[1] 3
#[1] "should be between the numbers"
#[1] 4
#[1] "should be between the numbers"
```

You can still use `a <- list(1:4)` but in which case you have to change the loop as :

```
for (i in a[[1]]) {
  print(i)
  print("should be between the numbers")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the code as below.

```r
a<-(1:4)
for (i in a){
  print(i)
  print("should be between the numbers")
}

#[1] 1
#[1] "should be between the numbers"
#[1] 2
#[1] "should be between the numbers"
#[1] 3
#[1] "should be between the numbers"
#[1] 4
#[1] "should be between the numbers"
```